# How to solve NullPointerException in Bitmap decleration.

Tags: java, android, bitmap, compiler-errors

I'm getting an error here that says,

```
at android.graphics.Bitmap_Delegate.nativeWidth(Bitmap_Delegate.java:291)
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeWidth(Bitmap.java)
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth(Bitmap.java:785)
```

The DDMS says I'm getting an error at line 66 of the ViewingWindow class which is where the int bitmapX is declared and initialized:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (canvas == null) throw new NullPointerException();

        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        if (Monitor.getCurrent() == Monitor.TYPE.GREEN) bitmap = greenBitmap;
        else bitmap = redBitmap;

        int bitmapX = bitmap.getWidth() / 2;
        int bitmapY = bitmap.getHeight() / 2;

        int parentX = parentWidth / 2;
        int parentY = parentHeight / 2;

        int centerX = parentX - bitmapX;
        int centerY = parentY - bitmapY;

        matrix.reset();
        matrix.postTranslate(centerX, centerY);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, matrix, paint);
    }
```

Why am I getting such an error? Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Here is the initialized variables of greenBitmap and redBitmap:

```
private static Bitmap greenBitmap = null;
    private static Bitmap redBitmap = null;

    private static int parentWidth = 0;
    private static int parentHeight = 0;

    public ViewingWindow(Context context, AttributeSet attr) {
        super(context, attr);

        greenBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.green_icon);
        redBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.red_icon);
    }

    public ViewingWindow(Context context) {
        super(context);

        greenBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.green_icon);
        redBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.red_icon);
    }
```

The full error from DDMS:

```
11-21 20:53:44.959: E/AndroidRuntime(521): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-21 20:53:44.959: E/AndroidRuntime(521): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-21 20:53:44.959: E/AndroidRuntime(521):  at com.ali.nazzal.sciencefairheartrateproject.ViewingWindow.onDraw(ViewingWindow.java:66)
11-21 20:53:44.959: E/AndroidRuntime(521):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6740)
11-21 20:53:44.959: E/AndroidRuntime(521):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
11-21 20:53:44.959: E/AndroidRuntime(521):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
11-21 20:53:44.959: E/AndroidRuntime(521):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
11-21 20:53:44.959: E/AndroidRuntime(521):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
11-21 20:53:44.959: E/AndroidRuntime(521):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
11-21 20:53:44.959: E/AndroidRuntime(521):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
11-21 20:53:44.959: E/AndroidRuntime(521):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
11-21 20:53:44.959: E/AndroidRuntime(521):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
11-21 20:53:44.959: E/AndroidRuntime(521):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
11-21 20:53:44.959: E/AndroidRuntime(521):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
11-21 20:53:44.959: E/AndroidRuntime(521):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)
11-21 20:53:44.959: E/AndroidRuntime(521):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
11-21 20:53:44.959: E/AndroidRuntime(521):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1842)
11-21 20:53:44.959: E/AndroidRuntime(521):  at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1407)
11-21 20:53:44.959: E/AndroidRuntime(521):  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1163)
11-21 20:53:44.959: E/AndroidRuntime(521):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
11-21 20:53:44.959: E/AndroidRuntime(521):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-21 20:53:44.959: E/AndroidRuntime(521):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-21 20:53:44.959: E/AndroidRuntime(521):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
11-21 20:53:44.959: E/AndroidRuntime(521):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-21 20:53:44.959: E/AndroidRuntime(521):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-21 20:53:44.959: E/AndroidRuntime(521):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
11-21 20:53:44.959: E/AndroidRuntime(521):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
11-21 20:53:44.959: E/AndroidRuntime(521):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

----------------------------New Error from DDMS---------------------------------

```
  11-21 21:49:44.699: E/AndroidRuntime(551): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    11-21 21:49:44.699: E/AndroidRuntime(551): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ali.nazzal.sciencefairheartrateproject/com.ali.nazzal.sciencefairheartrateproject.Monitor}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class com.ali.nazzal.sciencefairheartrateproject.ViewingWindow
    11-21 21:49:44.699: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
    11-21 21:49:44.699: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
    11-21 21:49:44.699: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
    11-21 21:49:44.699: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
    11-21 21:49:44.699: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    11-21 21:49:44.699: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    11-21 21:49:44.699: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
    11-21 21:49:44.699: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    11-21 21:49:44.699: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    11-21 21:49:44.699: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
    11-21 21:49:44.699: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
    11-21 21:49:44.699: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    11-21 21:49:44.699: E/AndroidRuntime(551): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class com.ali.nazzal.sciencefairheartrateproject.ViewingWindow
    11-21 21:49:44.699: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:503)
    11-21 21:49:44.699: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:565)
    11-21 21:49:44.699: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
    11-21 21:49:44.699: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:621)
    11-21 21:49:44.699: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:621)
    11-21 21:49:44.699: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
    11-21 21:49:44.699: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
    11-21 21:49:44.699: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
    11-21 21:49:44.699: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:198)
    11-21 21:49:44.699: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1647)
    11-21 21:49:44.699: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at com.ali.nazzal.sciencefairheartrateproject.Monitor.onCreate(Monitor.java:60)
    11-21 21:49:44.699: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
    11-21 21:49:44.699: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
    11-21 21:49:44.699: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  ... 11 more
    11-21 21:49:44.699: E/AndroidRuntime(551): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: ViewingWindow(Context,AttributeSet)
    11-21 21:49:44.699: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at java.lang.Class.getMatchingConstructor(Class.java:660)
    11-21 21:49:44.699: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:477)
    11-21 21:49:44.699: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:475)
    11-21 
21:49:44.699: E/AndroidRuntime(551):    ... 23 more
```

Comment: What is `bitmap` at that point? `greenBitmap` or `redBitmap`? One of those is `null` it looks like.

Comment: The problem is not `bitmap`, but `greeenBitmap` or `redBitmap` is null. Make sure they are not null.

Comment: But it seems that the stack trace says that the null pointer is happening at android.graphics.Bitmap_Delegate.nativeWidth(Bitmap_Delegate.java:291) not at ViewingWindow:66... can you post the full error stack trace please?

Comment: @LawrenceChoy I put the code in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this constructor to `ViewingWindow:`

```
public ViewingWindow(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attr, defStyle);

        greenBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.green_icon);
        redBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.red_icon);
    }
```

Comment: I did that and the error changed. It doesn't reference line 66 anymore. It can't inflate the class. I'll put the error in my question.

Comment: @Navio53 did you **replaced** the constructor instead of adding it? In the new error it said it cannot find the constructor `ViewingWindow(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)`

Comment: Ya, I went and added it the constructor without replacing the original, and I'm getting the same error as the first set of errors I posted up in my question.

Comment: @Navio53 Can you try to debug and see when you first enter `onDraw()`, are both `greenBitmap` and `redBitmap` not null? Also is `bitmap` not null just before the line `int bitmapX = bitmap.getWidth() / 2;`?

Comment: bitmap is null before and on     int bitmapX = bitmap.getWidth() / 2;    greenBitmap and redBitmap are not showing as I enter the onDraw() method.

Comment: I don't understand how bitmap could be null right when it reaches: int bitmapX = bitmap.getWidth() / 2. It shouldn't be null, because I initialized bitmap using the if statement just before bitmapX.

Comment: I figured what was the problem. The icons that I was setting greenBitmap and redBitmap to wouldn't even open up on windows image viewer. I had to go get the icons again, and put them through the folder and not just drag and drop. Thank you for your help I really appreciate it.